# YARN hadoop error java heap space

Tags: java, hadoop, memory, heap-memory, hadoop-yarn

I use YARN on hadoop 2.6.0. When I ran an mapreduce job, I got an error like this :

```
15/03/12 22:22:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426132548565_0003_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
15/03/12 22:22:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426132548565_0003_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
15/03/12 22:23:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1426132548565_0003_m_000002_2, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
```

Am I false to configure the java.opts propery. Is that error because of that configuration? Are there any connection between memory settings on yarn-site and mapred-site?

I very confused, I need your suggest all Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the container exceeds the memory/CPU usage, it is killed by the application master. In your case, the mappers might be using excess memory. Try adding the following configurations:

In mapred-site.xml:

```html
 <property>
   <name> mapreduce.map.memory.mb </name>
   <value>1024</value>
   <description>Enter The amount of memory to request from the scheduler for each map task. </description>
 </property>
```

The default value is 1024, try increasing it to 2048.

I would suggest you to restart the cluster after changing the configurations